# finding average for the same date in different years

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the following DataFrame:

```
df
Out[1]: 
              temp_C
date          
2013-01-01    12
2013-01-02    11
2013-01-03    10
2013-01-04     9
2013-01-05    10
2013-01-06    10
2013-01-07    11
2013-01-08    12
2013-01-09    14
2013-01-10    14
2013-01-11    12
2013-01-12    12
2013-01-13    11
2013-01-14    10
2013-01-15    10
2013-01-16    12
2013-01-17    13
...   
2017-01-02     8
2017-01-03     8
2017-01-04     8
2017-01-05     9
2017-01-06     9
2017-01-07    10
2017-01-08    12
2017-01-09    14
2017-01-10    14
2017-01-11    10
2017-01-12    10
2017-01-13    11
2017-01-14    14
2017-01-15    13
2017-01-16    10
2017-01-17     9
[1770 rows x 1 columns]
```

What I need to do is to group the values by the day of the year, find the mean (or median) values of each group, and thus obtaining a new DataFrame, in which the values of each day is the mean/median/... of all the values for the same day.

Here's an example:

```
df_grouped
Out[2]: 
              temp_C
date
2013-01-01    12
2014-01-01    10
2015-01-01    10
2016-01-01    12
2017-01-01    11
2013-01-02    11
2014-01-02    10
....
2016-12-31    8
2017-12-31    7

df_mean
Out[3]: 
              temp_C
date
1970-01-01    11 #the year is not meaningful anymore
1970-01-02    11.4
1970-01-03    12.5
....
1970-12-30    7.5
1970-12-31    7.5
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'temp_C': range(10)},
    pd.to_datetime([
        '2010-01-23', '2012-03-30',
        '2013-01-23', '2013-03-30',
        '2014-01-23', '2014-03-30',
        '2016-01-23', '2015-03-30',
        '2017-01-23', '2017-03-30',
    ])
)
```

---

#### `groupby`

```
df.groupby('{:%m-%d}'.format).mean()

       temp_C
01-23       4
03-30       5
```

---

#### Explanation

Strings have a `format` method that you can use as a callable.  It takes arguments that get processed and interpolated as a new string.

`'{:%m-%d}'.format` is a callable that takes a single positional argument and gets processed by what is in the `{}` within the string.  In this case `'{:%m-%d}'` is specific to handling dates and the formatting can be better understood [here](http://www.strftime.org).  It says to when looking at a date, format it as month-day.

When passing a callable to `groupby` it applies that callable to each element of the index.  Since our index is `Datetime` then each element gets returned as the month and day.  That is precisely what we wanted in order to take our `mean`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. Just a question: in this case what do the {} brackets mean? or better: what purpose do they have?

Comment: I'll add more explanation in a bit.  I'm putting together an example.  Then I'll explain

Comment: @GGiacomo hope that helps.